# Coloring of a 4-sided figure with three colors

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I attached the image below for reference. I am trying to color the figure using three colors and find the number of distinguishable colorings.

The long sides of the figure are one side and not two short sides. We do not count reflections as indistinguishable

I was trying to solve it for  using casework: When the cross in the middle is all one color, and the short sides are both the same color, there are 3*3=9 ways to do that.

Then there are the cases where the cross is one color and the short sides are split one and one (these are rotations) so that is another 3*3/3=3.

Then when the cross is two different colors, and sides same color: 6*3/2=9

Then cross different colors, sides different colors: 6*3/2=9

So I'm getting 30 ways to do this. But I'm looking for a nicer solutions that doesn't involve casework. Is there a way to do this (possibly with orbits?) What about if reflections do count? Then what happens?

[Picture for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsPQp.png)

Comment: What are you coloring? edges? Do you search for a proper coloring (two adjacent edges must be colored differently)? Why represent the figure like this if the crossing does not matter? You could have drawn a square

Comment: @caduk Why would the crossing not matter? It seems clear to me after doing the math that it doesn't, but what is the rigorous logic? Also I believe we are using a rectangle and not a square.

Comment: @MrMustache The constraints of the problem only relies on incidence relationship between the lines, and not at all on their absolute position. Thus, this is a graph colouring problem (edge coloring) that does not depend on any particular embedding of the graph.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that the two long sides cross does not actually matter. From @caduk's comment, if I understand what you're asking, this is the same as finding the number of ways to paint the sides of a rectangle with three colors.

Since you mentioned orbits, I assume you are familiar with how to use groups. [Burnside's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma) should be applied here.

If you need another hint, let me know.